# How can I select and hide a Class containing TEXT

Tags: javascript

I have html looking like this :

```
<div class="row">Something</div>
<div class="row">Text</div>
<div class="row">Something</div>
```

I can't touch the DOM so class will always be "row".

Actual Code :

```
<div class="row">
<label class="ag label" for="firstname" opt-for="firstname-input" opt-char-limit="null">First Name</label>
<input class="ad"=""="" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="row">
<label class="ag label" for="lastname" opt-for="lastname-input" opt-char-limit="null">HideThisField</label>
<input class="ad"=""="" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="row">
<label class="ag label" for="email" opt-for="email-input" opt-char-limit="null">Email</label>
<input class="ad" required="" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="">
</div>
```

I need target the div containing "Text" and set it as display:none. In Javascript.

Also I will have multiple "Text" to hide their own row.

Not sure where to get started, thanks for any help!

Comment: It is not valid in HTML to have multiple identical id values in one document. Is this really the HTML you are working with?

Comment: "Something" is a <label> and an <input>. Please post a real example of HTML you are working with.

Comment: *"Not that it should matter but "Something" is a <label> and an <input>"*, that definitely matters. *"each label/input having the same **unique** ID."*, notice anything odd in that sentence? Two things cannot have the same unique ID, otherwise it's not unique.

Comment: Yololo yolala something here something there looks like this but it's not. What is it? :) Imagine a person shares the same social ID number as yours. That would be an issue, right? learn about classes.

Comment: `closest` is a jQuery method. You've not tagged this with jQuery. You should also show your attempts. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ for more information.

Comment: @Mike: [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) is not - necessarily - jQuery, despite sharing the same method name. It is, however, identified as *experimental*, so probably should not be relied upon at this point.

Comment: "*Not that it should matter but "Something" is a `<label>` and an `<input>`, each label/input having the same unique ID.*" - two things: 1. oh, it matters and it *should* matter (this is invalid HTML, which naturally causes JavaScript problems by design) and, 2. rather than 'explaining' your HTML, could you show it?

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for the link. Haven't been keeping up on the latest and greatest :).

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect actual code. This is a form generated by a page builder so what they push out is outside of my control.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you can't have several elements with the same ID.

You should use a class instead.

Example :

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) 
  if (elems[i].innerHTML === 'Text') 
    elems[i].style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<div class="row">Something</div>
<div class="row">Something</div>
<div class="row">Text</div>
<div class="row">Something</div>
```

Comment: why the `break`?

Comment: The OP said 'I can't touch the DOM so id will always be "row"'

Comment: The break is only performance. You stop looking after you find the ocurrence

Comment: *"Also I will have **multiple** "Text" to hide their own row"*, the break makes it wrong.

Comment: $( "div:contains('Text')" ).hide(), no need to waste time with vanilla js for this task...

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev jQuery isn't tagged.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, yep and that is why I just commented. :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML with multiple ids is invalid. If you really can't change the DOM, you're in for a hard timenough.

Here are some of your options if you cant:

Use the jQuery.contains selector which checks for text content: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Failing that, you'll have to use a combination of selectors like all inputs with such and such a class and navigate upwards to the outer divs etc: jQuery has a multitude of selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
    Array.from(divs, div => {
       if (div.textContent.indexOf("text") >= 0) {
        div.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Also you have to replace all id rows(since you can't have same id on the page) with class rows.

Best